# Using Snackbar.Callback for Undo-Delete action

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a working linear `RecyclerView` with swipe-to-delete and everything is good.
However, when I try the `Snackbar.Callback` to create a "undo" action, I get list error's like "invalid Index", the item is swiped away then immediately reappears, and even "Inconsistency detected" errors. Any one see something odd in the code?

```
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            // item position
            final int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            communicator.remove(pos);
            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);

            Snackbar.make(view, R.string.notice_removed, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                            switch (event) {
                                case Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION:
                                     recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(pos);
                                     break;
                                default:
                                    communicator.remove(pos);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setAction(R.string.action_undo, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .show();

            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `final int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` is not good idea. Because final cause `pos` holds wrong index that you need in your SnackBar CallBack listener. You can use `view.getTag` and `view.setTag` for holding right index of your adapter position. Maybe this can help you:

```
    @Override
    public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        // hold position in view item
        int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        view.setTag(pos);
        communicator.remove(pos);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        //Snackbar.make(view, R.string.notice_removed, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Snackbar.make(view, R.string.notice_removed, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                        //get position from view item of snackbar that you set it before.
                        int position = (int)snackbar.getView().getTag();
                        switch (event) {
                            case Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION:
                                 recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
                                 break;
                            default:
                                communicator.remove(position);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setAction(R.string.action_undo, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .show();

        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount());
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Majid, `pos` in the code you posted doesnt look initialized so how does `setTag(object)` affect the code?

Comment: OK @Frank, You right. I have edited the code. You have to use `position` variable in CallBack method.

Comment: I need access to it in the Snackbar callback methods so the IDE needs it to be final. Any other solutions?

Comment: @Frank, I have edited it again for this issue. Did you try that?

Comment: You can access to it by `position` variable that I got it from `view.getTag`. `getTag`  used for getting current position that you have saved it before with `setTag`.